# Bash for splitting and auto cropping PDF files

Tags: bash, pdf, split, extract, crop

I have a long PDF file made of various numerized pages. In each page there's a small ticket that I would like to extract and save in a new different file.

I assume that I have to split the long PDF file in various pages and auto crop each ones to keep the small ticket.

Is there a bash script (or other) that could help me for that ?

Regards

Comment: not bash by itself but have a look @ http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are cropping in the same place on each page, we can use [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/) to do this:

First, crop all the pages...

```
cpdf -crop "200 300 150 200" in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

Then, split them out...

```
cpdf -split out.pdf -o file%%%.pdf
```